# Three.js RGBE Loader load HDR with URL

Tags: three.js, xmlhttprequest

I want to load an HDR into my scene but I don't have the file stored locally, it is a URL. It seems like the RGBE Loader has a problem with that because it is the wrong file format. Here's the error message: `THREE.RGBELoader Bad File Format: bad initial token`. I guess I can't just pass the URL but I don't know what to do with it.

This is the code of my loader:

```
import { UnsignedByteType, PMREMGenerator } from "three";

import { RGBELoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader";

export default function initRGBE(renderer, scene, hdr) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(hdr);
    new RGBELoader().setDataType(UnsignedByteType).load(
      hdr,
      texture => {
        const pmremGenerator = new PMREMGenerator(renderer);
        pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();
        const envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;
        scene.environment = envMap;
        texture.dispose();
        pmremGenerator.dispose();
        resolve();
      },
      xhr => {
        console.log(`HDR ${Math.floor((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100)}% loaded`);
      },
      err => {
        reject(new Error(err));
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was no problem with my code. The problem was my Webpack config (I use Vue). Didn't realize it because webpack doesn't throw an error when you don't use a local file. This solution is Vue specific but I think you can just put it in a regular Webpack config file.

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [{ test: /\.hdr$/, use: "url-loader" }]
    }
  }
};
```